# How to webscrape an iFrame that has internal iFrames?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new at webscraping. I have our college website that has results in an iFrame. The results iFrame has many internal links that redirect or load the iFrame with respective result.
How can I scrape the marks of my semester using beautifulsoup.

Link: http://cvr.ac.in/home4/index.php/academics/results
In the iFrame displayed I want to scrape in the link, lets say "B.Tech IV YEAR II SEM Main Examinations (R15-B16) held in August-2020"

Earlier they had a separate results page without frames and I could soup it something like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
result = requests.post("<old url>", data={'srno':'<number>'})
s = bs(result.content, 'lxml')
//skim thru results
```

But I am not sure how to do it in frames case. Help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get data from AUGUST 2020 link, you can use this example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://cvr.ac.in/home4/index.php/academics/results'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0'}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')
base_url = 'https://' + soup.iframe['src'].replace('https://', '').split('/')[0]
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(soup.iframe['src'], headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')
# select AUGUST 2020 link:
link = base_url + soup.select_one('a:contains("AUGUST 2020")')['href']

data = {
    'srno': "1111",     # <-- Change to your desired ROLL number
    'type': "roll",
    'phase1':  ""
}
soup = BeautifulSoup( requests.post(link, data=data, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser' )

# parse your required data from soup
# ...
```

Comment: Thanks!! Works like charm.
I was thinking whether I was limited by technology and was thinking to switch to selenium. But thanks to you, that I understand BS even more.